# Does resetting a QValidator leak memory?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I'm curious if anyone knows whether removing a `QValidator` by resetting it to zero will leak memory. The [QT Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#setValidator) mentions that the validator is "removed", but does that also imply that it is deleted?

An example of what I mean...

```
QLineEdit edit;
edit.setValidator(new QIntValidator(0,100));

// .... use the line edit

edit.setValidator(0);
```

Comment: Remember that a parent will keep a list of the child QObjects and when the parent is destroyed that it will free its children. I would expect QIntValidator to be a child of QLineEdit. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject

Comment: @drescherjm It seems that it is not correct, see my answer please, I added explanation, lineEdit does not take ownership.

Comment: @Chernobyl it appears you are correct. Here is what the internals of Qt-4.8.6 has: `void setValidator(const QValidator *v) { m_validator = const_cast<QValidator*>(v); }` This is from the file: qlinecontrol_p.h

Comment: @drescherjm I saw this, just didn't add this to answer, I added example of code and output, I think it is enough to prove that.

Comment: @drescherjm I think that it doesn't take ownership of the validator because it allows you to use a single validator instance by multiple widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `0` will not delete `validator`, only removes `validator` from `lineEdit`. If you still want use

```
edit.setValidator(new QIntValidator(0,100));
```

then you can delete it with:

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new Validator);
QValidator *vaal = const_cast<QValidator *>(ui->lineEdit->validator());//validator returns const, we use const_cast to avoid problems
vaal->deleteLater();
```

or

```
(const_cast<QValidator *>(ui->lineEdit->validator()))->deleteLater();
//here we just does not create unnecessary QValidator *vaal
```

where `Validator` is a subclass with:

```
Validator::~Validator()
{
   qDebug() <<"~Validator";
}
```

Output is:

```
~Validator
```

Or use just:

```
Validator *vaal = new Validator;
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(vaal);
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(0);
vaal->deleteLater();
```

Output is same.

Also when you use `setValidator` `QLineEdit` does not take ownership of this `validator`. See next code:

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0,100,this));
qDebug() << ui->lineEdit->validator()->parent();
```

Output in my case: `MainWindow(0x28fdc8, name = "MainWindow")` As you can see it is not a `lineEdit`!

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0,100));
qDebug() << ui->lineEdit->validator()->parent();
```

Output is: `QObject(0x0)`

Deletion of `validator` is only your responsibility.

Comment: So when I do `ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0,100,this));` , `this` will delete validator cretaed with new? No memory leak in such a case? Maybe, it is better to `ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0,100,ui->lineEdit));` or it does not matter?

Comment: @Oleksandra You need to read about parent-child relationship in Qt. If you use Qt Designer then parent of lineEdit is centralWidget and it's parent is "this". So it's doesn't matter this or lineEdit, for clean code use "this". About leak: this validator will be deleted with "this"(with MainWindow class for example). If you need de-allocate memory earlier then you should delete validator by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Just set the parent of the validator, e. g.:

```
QLineEdit edit;
edit.setValidator(new QIntValidator(0,100,&edit));
```

In this case, the destructor of the QLineEdit will delete the validator.